# T-SQL - Adding FK to table, make it do drop/null/efault automagically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

If I had two tables where I need to add a new foreign key to, say:

```
ALTER TABLE [release_user] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [user_release] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([user_id]) REFERENCES [user_table] ([user_id]) 
                ON DELETE CASCADE
```

If there are records in the `release_user` table that do not have a matching ID in the `user_table`, the command will fail. I expect that.

However, is there a way to create the FK, and have it automatically delete (`DELETE CASCADE`) the records that would cause the FK to fail?

(Or, for example, if I used `DELETE SET NULL`, would null out the record's field in the `release_user` table?)

Comment: Short answer - no. You need to clean up your data BEFORE you add the constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could delete them first?

[DB_FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c22c910405c913a0bbb587306e56aff)

```
delete from ru
from release_user ru
left join user_table ut
on ut.user_id = ru.user_id
where ut.user_id is null
```

Then, add your constraint.

Comment: Thanks - would a SQL along the following work as well? `DELETE FROM release_user ru WHERE ru.user_id NOT IN (SELECT  user_id FROM user_table)`

Comment: Yes. You could also use NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 1):

Can try by using trigger as below
(can refer the actual syntax below sample just gives the logic via trigger )

```
   Create Trigger delete_check 
    Before Insert   on 
    release_user
    For EACH Row 

   If( Select count( * ) from 
        inserted where :New.ID NOT In 
     (Select Id from user_table ) >=1)
   {  dbms_output.put_line("dont insert")
     either
     < delete from release_user where 
      id =:new.id>
       or <insert into user_table 
        values(:New.id)> (to avoid 
        constraint error on insert)
    }
    END
```